# Bitmap to Mat? android opencv

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap

Hi i have my Bitmap object that i need to convert in Mat object .I saw that somebody used the bitmaptoMat function,but in my Utils package i have a lot of function with points list input to get Mat output but i have my Bitmap file.I tried another solution: Imgcodecs.imread that need string input,and i guess it needs the images path but i tried giving uri.toString() but it doesnt work.What can i do?
This is my Bitmap:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

Import

```
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
```

And then use the function:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
Mat imgMAT = new Mat (bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);    
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, imgMAT);
```

Comment: i did it..but next,i need to create superpixel object and after "                SuperpixelSLIC x=Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC(g,Ximgproc.SLIC,100,3);" the application break down, (g is my Mat object) and i get "cannot resolve corresponding jni function android studio"

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointer to bitmap, to generate a Mat file.
I did this with QT and it looks like this :

```
QImage  img((uchar*)frame->data(), frame->width(), frame->height(), QImage::Format::Format_RGB888);
```

I did it in opencv, but I don't remember the exact constructor:
try to do something like this:

```
cv::Mat bitmapMat = cv::Mat(bitmap.height, bitmap.width, CV_8UC1, bitmap.data());
```

or

```
cv::Mat bitmapMat = cv::Mat(Size _size, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP);
```

Comment: tried with Mat g=new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(),bitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC1), but i get error

Comment: do you have 1 channel image or 3 channel image? also it might be, that in opencv size is stored in different way, so you will have to do width, height.  Which error did you get? You dont need CvType. (just CV_8UC1 for 1 grayscale and CV_8UC3 for rgb )